# Global access, XML File (Setting file) values

Tags: c#, settings

I use a custom XML to save my application setting (I am not interested in setting file or config file). I would like to read that settings and keep it to use it in other classes whenever necessary. What is the best way? Using a static class or any other ways?

Comment: If you are still about to execute code from static constructor, see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say having a static class will do the job, I would just suggest paying attention to:

- having static constructor, where the xml file will be parsed and values read and assigned into corresponding fields.
- having default values, that will be assigned, if some data (or worst case whole xml file) will be missing
- using public static auto-properties, which will only have getters. Hide your private fields.

**EDIT**

Reading the XML file from static constructor of static class:

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
    //this is where we store the xml file line after line
    private static List<string> _xmlLines;

    //this is the class' static constructor
    //this code will be the first to run (you do not have to call it, it's automated)
    static MyStaticClass()
    {
        _xmlLines = new List<string>();

        using (System.IO.StreamReader xml = new System.IO.StreamReader("yourFile.xml"))
            {
                string line = null;
                while ((line = xml.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    _xmlLines.Add(line);
                }
            }
            //remember to catch your exceptions here
    }

    //this is the get-only auto property
    public static List<string> XmlLines
    {
        get
        {
            return _xmlLines;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: This is **not** production ready code, the types and logic of e.g. parsing the file are up to you, but I hope for demonstrative purposes, the code should be okay.
If there is anything unclear, feel free to ask *(but remember that the more info you provide, the more accurate the answers can be)*.